# Recommendation needed: Rails, Postgres and fuzzy full text search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, full-text-search, levenshtein-distance, n-gram

I have Rails app with a Postgres backend.

I need to add full text search which would allow fuzzy searches based on Levenshtein distance or other similar metrics. Add the fact that the lexer/stemmer has to work with non-English words (it would be ok to just switch language-dependent features off when lexing, to not mess with the target language which may have meaningful words considered by English engine as irrelevant).

I guess Postgres' tsearch won't apply here as it doesn't have fuzzy search -- please correct me if I'm wrong.

What are possible combinations of backends & plugins? It'd like to prefer solutions which add less to the infrastructure (eg. if Postgres can have fuzzy fts, why use external Lucene); OTOH, the quality of Rails plugins involved is important as well.

What would you recommend?

**update**: seems like I'd need rather n-gram based metrics than Levenshtein.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails + Postgres + Solr + Sunspot

[Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) is based on Lucene so you can take advantage of all Lucene features. [Sunspot](http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/) is an excellent Ruby wrapper for Solr API.
Both Sunspot and Solr work great with Rails and PostgreSQL, I used it for a project no more than one month ago.

Comment: Can you tell in short what exactly is a benefit of using Solr over plain Lucene?

Comment: Basically, with Solr you can use Lucene over the network. See http://www.lucidimagination.com/Community/Hear-from-the-Experts/Articles/Introduction-Apache-Lucene-and-Solr

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL comes with an extension called [pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/pgtrgm.html) (in the contrib/ directory). In my experience, it is too slow (more like a proof-of-concept implementation), but for your application it might work.

Answer (score 0):

[texticle](https://github.com/tenderlove/texticle) offers beta fuzzy search for Postgres.